# JavaFx labeled Pie Chart

Tags: javafx, pie-chart

I want display a label on each piece of a pieChart, which shows the current pievalue.

I tried it already with a StackPane, but I have still problems with the positioning of the label.
The labels are displayed in the middle of the pieChart, but I want to display them in the middle of each piece.

```
        for (PieChart.Data data : elements) {               
            Label valueLabel = new Label(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()));
            valueLabel.setTranslateX(data.getNode().getLayoutX());
            valueLabel.setTranslateY(data.getNode().getLayoutY());
            valueLabel.setVisible(true);

            pieChartStackPane.getChildren().add(valueLabel);
            valueLabel.toFront();
        }
```

Comment: The PieChartData already has a `Label`, are you looking to add an extra label?

Comment: Yes, I want to add labels directly on the piechart with the pieValues.